# Ruby - calculate returns between each elements of an array

Tags: ruby

I have to calculate returns between each elements of an array

Please see a sample of it:

```
nav = ["100.00", "86.21", "84.65", "82.46", "86.94"]
```

and here's the loop I used:

```
0.upto(nav.count - 2) do |i|
  perf = (nav[i + 1].to_f / nav[i].to_f - 1) * 100
  p perf
end
```

It works, but my point is all about the last element of the array.

First I wanted to use something like:

```
nav.length.times do 
  ... 
end
```

Then, I used:

```
0.upto(nav.count - 2)
```

in order to avoid the calculation of the (last value + 1) which would be nil.

However, I would be pleased to know if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `nav.inject {|a, b| p b.to_f/a*100; b}`

Comment: the term is "pairwise combinations". In Ruby: enumerable.each_cons(2).map { |a, b| ... }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nav.map(&:to_f).each_cons(2){|a,b| p (b/a-1)*100}
#=> -13.790000000000003
#=> -1.809534856745143
#=> -2.587123449497941
#=> 5.432937181663844
#=>  => nil
```

and if you need to return an array of values:

```
nav.map(&:to_f).each_cons(2).inject([]){|ar,(a,b)| ar << (b/a-1)*100}
#=> [-13.790000000000003, -1.809534856745143, -2.587123449497941, 5.432937181663844]
```

> On the second example: this inject construction is better known as "map" ;-) – @tokland

```
nav.map(&:to_f).each_cons(2).map{|a,b| (b/a-1)*100}
```

Comment: On the second example: this inject construction is better known as "map" ;-)

Comment: @tokland: How will `map` work, given that the array has 1 fewer element than the input array?

Comment: `each_cons(2)` will produce an enumerator with each pair, not each value, so it has the same number of elements as the results.

Comment: This can be simplified to just `nav.map(&:to_f).each_cons(2).map {|a,b| (b/a-1)*100}`.

Comment: @Platinum: See glenn's comment, that's exactly what I was pointing out on my first comment: enumerable.inject( { |arr, x| arr << ... } is in fact enumerable.map { |x| ... }

Comment: @tokland, glenn mcdonald :) thanks guys. I was carried away by all this functions

Answer (score 0):

You might favor [`Enumerable#inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494):

```
nav = ["100.00", "86.21", "84.65", "82.46", "86.94"]
i = 0
perf_array = nav.inject([]) do |result, elem|
  i = i + 1
  resultpush((nav[i].to_f / nav[i - 1].to_f - 1) * 100)
end

# Now perf_array contains each of your margins
```

EDIT: Actually `each_cons` is better (oops! Oh well, learn something new every day):

```
nav = ["100.00", "86.21", "84.65", "82.46", "86.94"]
perf_array = []
nav.map(&:to_f).each_cons(2) { |a, b| perf_array.push(b/a - 1) * 100 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `inject` method. This gives you an idea of how it works:

```
irb> nav.inject { |a, b| puts "#{a}, #{b}"; b }
100.00, 86.21
86.21, 84.65
84.65, 82.46
82.46, 86.94
```

Here is how your code looks using `inject`:

```
nav.inject do |a, b|
  perf = (b.to_f / a.to_f - 1) * 100
  p perf

  # return b, which will become the new a in the next iteration
  b
end
```